# Kubernetes "Unable to register node" with cloud-provider=aws

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I'm trying to run `kubelet` with `--cloud-provider=aws` flag but it fails with the following error:

> kubelet_node_status.go:107] Unable to register node "ip-172-28-68-69.eu-west-1.compute.internal" with API server: nodes "ip-172-28-68-69.eu-west-1.compute.internal" is forbidden: node "k8s-master.my.fqdn" cannot modify node "ip-172-28-68-69.eu-west-1.compute.internal"

I already tried to set `--host-override` flag to `"k8s-master.my.fqdn"` with no success.

```
(kubectl get nodes:
NAME                    STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s.my.fqdn             Ready     <none>    29m       v1.8.1)
```

How should I start `kubelet` in order to successful register on/to AWS?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue in this way:

1. Don't change default amazon hostname to your own because `--host-override` flag isn't working.
2. Init node like: `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.233.0.0/16 --node-name=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)` or simply use kubespray as a cluster management solution.

BTW if you want to integrate with amazon it's better to leave amazon hostname as is. Same I found in kubespray doc:

> The next step is to make sure the hostnames in your inventory file are identical to your internal hostnames in AWS. This may look something like ip-111-222-333-444.us-west-2.compute.internal

Comment: Even leaving the amazon hostname as is, you may still run into this issue. I'm running into the following, where `<region>.compute` is dropped from the hostname: unable to register node "ip-172-28-68-69.eu-west-1.compute.internal" with API server: nodes "ip-172-28-68-69.eu-west-1.compute.internal" is forbidden: node "ip-172-28-68-69.internal" cannot modify node "ip-172-28-68-69.eu-west-1.compute.internal"